# android studio mp chart setting x-axis value to SQL database entries

Tags: android, sql, android-studio, formatting, mpandroidchart

I want to set my X-axis value in my mp chart in android studio. I want to set this value to time domain data. I have an SQL database with a selection of data along with a time stamp for each data. I want to set my axis to start at the hour and minutes on the left of the first data point. Thus, end with the last data point on the right.

At the moment my x axis is purely an incremental count. I wish to set each data point x value to:

- Hour:Minute:Second

E.g `18:53:29`

My SQL database entry 7 has the time stored as a string in the format of:

Below is my graph function: `java 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);`

```java
private void Graph(){
        float x =0;
        ArrayList<Entry> board_values = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Entry> board_yAXES = new ArrayList<>();

        XAxis xAxis = local_linechart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        Cursor data;
        data = BLE_DB.showData_Filtered();//Initialise

        data.moveToFirst();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.getCount(); i++) {
            //Counter
            if (Data_Spinner_value.equals("T1")) {
                float yaxis = Float.parseFloat(valueOf(data.getString(1)));
                data.moveToNext();
                x = x + 1;//Move to next Id
                board_yAXES.add(new Entry(yaxis, i));
                board_values.add(new Entry(x, yaxis));
            } else if (Data_Spinner_value.equals("T2")) {
                float yaxis = Float.parseFloat(valueOf(data.getString(2)));
                data.moveToNext();
                x = x + 1;//Move to next Id
                board_yAXES.add(new Entry(yaxis, i));
                board_values.add(new Entry(x, yaxis));
            } else if (Data_Spinner_value.equals("T3")) {
                float yaxis = Float.parseFloat(valueOf(data.getString(4)));
                data.moveToNext();
                x = x + 1;//Move to next Id
                board_yAXES.add(new Entry(yaxis, i));
                board_values.add(new Entry(x, yaxis));
            } else if (Data_Spinner_value.equals("T4")) {
                float yaxis = Float.parseFloat(valueOf(data.getString(5)));
                data.moveToNext();
                x = x + 1;//Move to next Id
                board_yAXES.add(new Entry(yaxis, i));
                board_values.add(new Entry(x, yaxis));
            } else if (Data_Spinner_value.equals("Pd")) {
                float yaxis = Float.parseFloat(valueOf(data.getString(6)));
                data.moveToNext();
                x = x + 1;//Move to next Id
                board_yAXES.add(new Entry(yaxis, i));
                board_values.add(new Entry(x, yaxis));
            }
        }
        LineDataSet set1;
        set1 = new LineDataSet(board_values, Data_Spinner_value);
        set1.setDrawIcons(false);
        set1.setDrawValues(false);
        set1.setDrawCircles(false);
        set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
        set1.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        set1.setLineWidth(1f);

        ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        dataSets.add(set1);
        local_linechart.getDescription().setText(sDay_of_week + " " + sDay + " " + sMonth + " " + sYear);

        LineData data_Series = new LineData(dataSets);
        local_linechart.setData(data_Series);
        local_linechart.invalidate();//Refresh the graph

    }
```

So my question is: **How do I go about changing this string to something I can insert to the values to display?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that You want to change XAxis labels so they look like "HH:mm:ss" instead of "1,2,3" etc. for your entries. Using MPAndroidChart library.

- firstly You should refer to the documentation of MP Android chart which you're using, especially the [ValueFormatter](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/formatting-data-values/) which lets you change the labels on the Axis.

According to the documentation You have to create Your own ValueFormatter for the Axis.

What I would do:

1. create an ArrayList to store the "HH:mm:ss" labels
2. while adding the data to the counters also create a "HH:mm:ss" label corresponding to that counter (e.g if x = 0, then you add your first label and so on) - that way, the indexes in your list of labels will match the counter value.
3. When done with the counters create a class extending ValueFormatter and pass the list of labels there:

   ```
   public class MyXAxisFormatter extends ValueFormatter {

       private ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();

       public MyXAxisFormatter(ArrayList<String> labels) {
           this.labels = labels;
       }

       @Override
       public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
           return labels.get(Math.round(value));
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add the ValueFormatter to your Chart:

   ```
   chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(MyXAxisFormatter())
   ```

When You attach a ValueFormatter to an Axis, it will assign the label returned by getFormattedValue() to a counter on the Axis.

Also, don't use my_variable naming in java. Java uses CamelCase as a practice for writing names of methods, variables, classes, packages and constants. So, instead of **board_values** use **boardValues** and so on.

Comment: I have tried to use your code, but the point 3 causes a host of errors. Firstly I presume DriversXAxisFormatter should be MyAxisFormatter. Also local_linechart.xAxis.valueFormatter = MyXAxisFormatter() states xAxis is undefinded

Comment: Yes, you're right, there were some kotlin thingies in that java snippet. I've fixed that now. Also keep in mind that it is written for MPAndroidChart v 3.0.3, so make sure You have the same version:
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
Also take a look at point 4, i've also fixed it - in java you have to use a getter: chart.getXAxis() and so on. That's my fault for being a little too used to kotlin.

Comment: I can see that IAxisValueFormatter interface is deprecated in 3.1.0 and getFormattedValue(Float, AxisBase) is deprecated too. In 3.1.0 lets extend ValueFormater() and override the correct method instead. For that You can check point 3, i have updated it.